# Return multi value form

Tags: .net, vb.net, return-value

```
Public Property [Name]() As Integer
        Get
            Return ds_DriverList.Tables("ds").Rows(ListViewDriver.SelectedItems.Item(0).Index)("DriverName")
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As Integer)

        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property [ID]() As Integer
        Get
            Return ds_DriverList.Tables("ds").Rows(ListViewDriver.SelectedItems.Item(0).Index)("DriverID")
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As Integer)

        End Set
    End Property
```

i want to return Name and ID at the same time from a window form.how to do it?
p/s:if only return ID, that is working, but i would like to return multi value

### UPDATE

```
Public Structure NameID
        Public Name As String
        Public ID As Integer
    End Structure

    Public Property ID() As NameID
        Get
            Return New NameID With {.Name = ds_DriverList.Tables("ds").Rows(ListViewDriver.SelectedItems.Item(0).Index)("DriverName"), .ID = ds_DriverList.Tables("ds").Rows(ListViewDriver.SelectedItems.Item(0).Index)("DriverID")}
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As NameID)

        End Set
    End Property
```

[image]
this is the return value. wrong...

`MsgBox(f.ID.ToString())`
this is how i get the return value

Comment: Please don't post answers in the question.  Post your own answer in the space provided below.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
Public Structure NameID
    Public Name As String
    Public ID As Integer
End Structure

Public Property NameID() As NameID
    Get
        Return New NameID with {.Name = ds_DriverList.Tables("ds").Rows(ListViewDriver.SelectedItems.Item(0).Index)("DriverName"), .ID = ds_DriverList.Tables("ds").Rows(ListViewDriver.SelectedItems.Item(0).Index)("DriverID") }
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As NameID)

    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: `Set(ByVal Value As Integer)` here what i should change the code?

Answer (score 0):

```
Public ReadOnly Property [DriverName]() As String
    Get
        Return ds_DriverList.Tables("ds").Rows(ListViewDriver.SelectedItems.Item(0).Index)("DriverName")
    End Get
End Property
Public ReadOnly Property [DriverID]() As String
    Get
        Return ds_DriverList.Tables("ds").Rows(ListViewDriver.SelectedItems.Item(0).Index)("DriverID")
    End Get
End Property
```

how to call get the form return

```
  Dim f As New DriverListForm
        If f.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            MsgBox(f.DriverID.ToString + " " + f.DriverName.ToString)
        Else
            MsgBox("Cancelled")
        End If
        f.Dispose()
```